# Modified Duration of Overnight Index Swaps

Tags: swaps

Is the modified duration of an overnight index swap zero or close to zero?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

An OIS has 2 legs, like any other swap. The float leg duration will be nearly zero, because apart from the ON period the rates are floating. The fixed leg, however, has the same duration as a 3m swap with the same fixed leg specification.